# Is it possible to import xpt file which includes more than 1,000,000 observations?

Tags: import, sas

I got a xpt file which includes more than 1,400,000 observations. However, when I import it into SAS using PROC COPY, the dataset in SAS was truncated to 1,000,000 observations. My guess is that there is a default value for SAS to import data. Any suggestion to import the complete data into SAS?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far...

Comment: I tried two ways to import: (1)libname xptfile xport 'C:\XPT Datasets';
libname sasfile 'C:\SAS Datasets';
data sasfile.ca125cec;
   set xptfile.ca125cec;
run; (2) Proc copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not a default issue with SAS XPT files, as this toy example shows:

```
libname xplib xport "c:\temp\test.xpt";

data xplib.forxpt;
  do x = 1 to 1e7;
    output;
  end;
run;

data test;
  set xplib.forxpt;
run;
```

I would suggest going back to whomever created the file and talking to them.  Perhaps they didn't correctly export it.  Or perhaps there are two datasets in the xpt file, one with 1M one with 400k.

You also may want to check your `obs` option, to make sure it's not set to 1m.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your code, The data I got only had 1M Obs. Would you mind instructing me how to check obs option? I didn't remember that I set it to 1m. Appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Appreciate it. I got 10M. The data I got from colleagues must have only 1M.